# performancetotal webdriverio plugin affects on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, webdriver-io

I linked Performace Total plugin (https://webdriver.io/docs/wdio-performancetotal-service/) with my  webdriver.io tests and once I added options to this plugin, I can't resolve the Jenkins problem which seems to be related with it.

Jenkins throws:

```
2023-06-27T21:45:20.714Z ERROR @wdio/runner: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:30225
23:45:20  [0-12]     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16)
23:45:20  [0-12] 2023-06-27T21:45:20.729Z ERROR @wdio/utils:shim: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
23:45:20  [0-12]     at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at validateString (node:internal/validators:120:11)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at Object.join (node:path:1172:7)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at FileWriter.getFilePath (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/si-client-fe/euro-test_custom_verify@2/node_modules/wdio-performancetotal-service/build/src/helpers/file-writer.js:78:31)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at PerformanceTotal.<anonymous> (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/si-client-fe/euro-test_custom_verify@2/node_modules/wdio-performancetotal-service/build/src/performance-total.js:85:47)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/si-client-fe/euro-test_custom_verify@2/node_modules/wdio-performancetotal-service/build/src/performance-total.js:8:71
23:45:20  [0-12]     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at __awaiter (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/si-client-fe/euro-test_custom_verify@2/node_modules/wdio-performancetotal-service/build/src/performance-total.js:4:12)
23:45:20  [0-12]     at PerformanceTotal.analyzeResults (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/si-client-fe/euro-test_custom_verify@2/node_modules/wdio-performancetotal-service/build/src/performance-total.js:77:16)
```

I just don't get it. Service in conf file looks like in doc or complety without any options and the problem still occurs:

```
services: [
      ['performancetotal',
      // The options (with default values)
        {
            disableAppendToExistingFile: false,
            performanceResultsFileName: "performance-results",
            dropResultsFromFailedTest: false,
            performanceResultsDirectory: "performance-results",
            analyzeByBrowser: false
        }]
      ]
```

Locally it works perfectly fine... Why?